# How can I log when reads to /dev/random block?

Tags: linux, logging, kernel

I've noticed that since updating my server to Debian Squeeze the amount of entropy as reported by /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail is much lower than it was before the upgrade.  I would like to know if this lower pool size is big enough to function with or if I need to look into getting more entropy sources.  I think having a way to log blocking reads of /dev/random would show whether I have enough entropy or not.

Comment: Are you sure you are short on entropy? I just checked my Debian Squeeze box and it seemed to have about the same entropy value as a CentOS box. Numbers varied from 160 to 190.

Comment: [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)'s logs show a clear drop after updating to Squeeze that hasn't recovered even with normal traffic.

Comment: As for the "is that short": that's the reason why I want to log blocking:  if reads are blocking I am short.

Comment: Just a suggestion: use `/dev/urandom` if it exists. Urandom doesn't block.

Comment: Try `rng-tools` (.deb package)

Comment: You should be fine with the entropy you have. `/dev/urandom` doesn't block because it will *generate entropy*  using hashes like SHA and MD5 (pseudo RNG), it's normally safe enough to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a library with your own implementation of `read(...)` or whatever function you use to read from `/dev/random` to wrap the actual call in profiling and logging methods. Then you should use a `LD_PRELOAD` env variable to insert your custom implementation of `read` before the system one.

Comment: It will not work for a statically-linked binary (granted: they are pretty rare nowadays).